# Process builder & schedule action issue

Tags: process-builder

We have two Process builders on Opportunity (both when a record is created or edited). The first one is executed when the  stageName is equals to 2 and update a datetime field (stageNameDate) with the run datetime . The second PB is executed when stageName is not equals to 5 and schedule an action to send an email 10 days after the stageNameDate field.

If the opp is created with stage equals to 2 the email is sent in that moment by the second PB instead of wait 10 days. The stageNameDate field is set correctly by the first PB, it is equals to the opp created date.

Why the email is sent immediately instead of schedule the action??

[image]

First PB

[image]

Second PB
[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of what the date was set to? The only way it would send immediately is if the date it's using is back-dated (already passed 10 days).

Comment: Even more, I have changed the first PB to update the date field with a future date instead of the run time (now() + 1)...same result, the email is sent immediately.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what the PB's criteria and scheduled action look like?

Comment: added images of both PB

Comment: Is there any reason why you have two separate PBs and not combine the two as separate Criteria in one single PB? I'd be interested in how it functions if you made it one.

Comment: Maybe makes sense but I would like to understand what is happening...:)

Comment: Hypothesis: when you have two PBs on same object, execution order is undefined. The second PB may not have a value for StageNameDate when executed so the date calc may default to today

Comment: @cropredy I was thinking the same as you but this theory doesn’t explain why the email is sent immediately, if the date is null the schedule action is not executed

Comment: If you have no PBs at all on the object, is there a date value set on that field (FechaEstado2__c)?

Comment: the first PB set that date

Comment: I am checking and the PB is working correctly on update, the email is scheduled perfectly. It seems the issue is only on create

Comment: I have added one immediate action to the 2nd PB (the PB who schedule the action) to update one of the text fields with the stageNameDate value, in order to see if that value is known in that specific moment and finally the result is the value is blank. Maybe that is the reason because the schedule action is executed immediately? in the documentation I can read 'If the field referenced by a schedule has a null value, Salesforce ignores the schedule and the associated actions aren’t executed' but in this case the field is blank no null.....not sure if this is the reason....